# Get caption of handle

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pinvoke

I got all `Child Windows` of *handle*, 

Now I want to get the caption of every Child Window by handle.

my code:

```
 For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProccess")
            Dim ChildrenList As New List(Of IntPtr)
            ChildrenList = GetChildWindows(p.MainWindowHandle)
            MsgBox(ChildrenList.Count) ' = 343
            For Each hh As IntPtr In ChildrenList

                 '  i want to do something like: MsgBox(getCaption(hh))

            Next
        Next
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you seen this site? http://pinvoke.net/

Comment: Did you mean you want to `FindWindow` Caption?

Comment: @WraithNath of course that i saw this site.

Comment: @spajce i mean to find the caption of the handle by the handle.

Comment: Child windows don't have captions if they are not MDI client windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the title of a window with the [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx) function. You'll need to p/invoke to it. You can find sample code for this at [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtext).

Answer (score 1):

**Source** : [#1](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowText.html) & [#2](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowTextLength.html)

---

By caption i hope you mean "The window Title text"

you have already created a list of window handle of child windows

for rest will be easy

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    Public Function GetText(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As String
        Dim length As Integer
        If hWnd.ToInt32 <= 0 Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)
        If length = 0 Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder("", length + 1)

        GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity)
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
```

Usage :

```
 For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProccess")
            Dim ChildrenList As New List(Of IntPtr)
            ChildrenList = GetChildWindows(p.MainWindowHandle)
            MsgBox(ChildrenList.Count) ' = 343
            For Each hh As IntPtr In ChildrenList

                 Dim caption As String = GetText(hh)
                 ' use the caption the way u want

            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Please do not copy code from another source without attribution. That is very bad form indeed.

Comment: sorry! & THNX FOR REMINDING!